# How Long Will An iOS 8 app Continue To Function On Device Installed By Xcode?

Tags: ios, ios8, app-store

I am relatively new to iOS development. I have recently acquired an Individual Apple Developers Account so I can test an app I developed for an individual in my community on his own tablet.

After disconnecting the USB cable I found that the app continues to function. According to this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289078/how-long-will-an-ios-app-continue-to-function-after-being-installed-for-testing) I have gathered that I have either 9 or 12 months to get feedback from the user of the app and smooth off the rough edges and add some more features before I **have to** upload the app to the App-Store.

I wasn't actually interested in marketing the app through the App-Store. I developed it for the learning experience it would provide -- and it was definitely an excellent learning experience. I fail to understand why people cannot develop their own apps and upload them their own devices and bypass the App-Store.

Could someone provide some clarity on this?

Comment: Since June it is no longer needed to have a dev account to test on devices.  The limitations are their to stop people from publishing to the masses on their own / through other channels. Because it is only one person and you have direct contact with him, there is nothing stopping you from installing it again after 12 months.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood, I found that the app wouldn't upload and run the device unless I had a Developer Account. Also, where I will be finishing my Computer Science degree by next May, I do not plan to remain in this area as there isn't many CS jobs in this area. So I will **need** to get this app so it is permanently install on the device. Which leads me to my next question: If I were to publish this app through the App-Store and my user formally downloads it will that make it **permanently installed** on his tablet ever If I were to let my Developers Account lapse for some unforeseen reason

Comment: Once your app is in the AppStore it's permanently there unless you take it down or Apple bans it if your app violates their T&C... Other than that the dev account is needed only to submit new binaries to AppStore. Also, once a user installs the app s/he also has permanent access through their Purchase History - even if you happen to take your app down. Taking down the app affects only the new users.

Answer (score 0):

Apple probably doesnt want people to bypass the app store, otherwise you could have sketchy apps floating around that didnt get vetted by Apple. and you dont have to upload to the app store, its just your provisioning profile that signed the app that you installed to your device would have expired and then it wouldnt run anymore, so would need to reinstall it to the device with an updated provisioning profile (which could require you to renew your developer licence, if thats what you are worried about)

Comment: Ive capitalised Apple, our lord and saviours name, but thats all you are getting :P

Answer (score 0):

I think it's for security reasons that Apple prevents direct installation to prevent unauthorized / malicious software to be widespread and some developers who didn't like this idea broke that security barrier and called it "jailbreaking."

However, this voids your device warranty (most likely if you bring a jailbroken phone to an Apple Store).

Comment: Okay! I can appreciate the idea of keeping malicious programming from making it to the general public. After some thought I suppose it would be possible for a person to develop a malicious app and distribute it on the sly. I can commend Apple for trying to protect its user base.